# Put sheet.cells(address/name as string) rather than column, row

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I want to put the cell's address/name as string rather than column, row.

```vb
ws - a worksheet
ows - another worksheet
cell is a string = "G5"
i and c are respectivly row and columns    

cell = ws.Cells(i, 1)

ows.Cells(cell).Value = ws.Cells(i, c)
```

That code brings out an error.

Comment: `ows.Range(cell).Value` not `ows.Cells(cell).Value`

Comment: Just curious, but did my post help you with a solution? If not, let me know and I'll see if I can't find another method to help.

Answer (score 10):

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Replace with your sheet name
Set ows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Replace with your sheet name

cell = ws.Cells(i, 1)

ows.Range(cell).Value = ws.Cells(i, c)
```

Range expects a string, such as "A5" or "A5:B5", where as Cells expects two numbers separated by a comma

```
 'Examples
 Cells(1,2) 
 Range("A5")
 Range("A5:B5")
 Range(Cells(10,4), Cells(8,3)) 'Use Cells as args for a Range
```

One other difference is Cells will return either one cell or all cells of a worksheet.